# Como fazer query contendo MAX e COUNT via LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, linq

Tenho o seguinte `model`:

```
 public class Crm_Analise
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string cod_item_CRM { get; set; }
    public string TAG { get; set; }
    public string data_creat { get; set; }
    public string modelo { get; set; }   
    public int cliente_CRM { get; set; }
}
```

Via *scaffolding* gerei o *controller* e as *views*.

Alterei a `View Index` para:

```
 <table class="table">
    <tr>          
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("TAG", "Index")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("ATUALIZAÇÃO", "Index")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("RELATÓRIOS", "Index")
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TAG)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.data_creat)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.modelo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Visualizar", "Details") 
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Então queria agrupar por `TAG`, sendo `MAX(data_creat)` e `COUNT(modelo)`.
Se fosse via SQL, eu faria:

```
SELECT TAG, MAX(data_creat) AS 'ATUALIZAÇÃO', COUNT(modelo) AS 'RELATÓRIOS'
FROM Crm_Analise
WHERE cliente_CRM = @cliente_CRM
GROUP BY TAG
```

Então no *controller* fiz:

```
// GET: Crm_Analise
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {

        if (Session["cod_cli"] != null)
        {
            int cod_cli = Convert.ToInt32(Session["cod_cli"]);

            var query = from s in db.Crm_Analise
                        select s;

            query = query.Where(s => s.cliente_CRM == cod_cli);

            return View(await query.ToListAsync());
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
    }
```

Mas como aplico o `MAX`, `COUNT` e o `GROUP BY`?

Atualização ref. a resposta do @Maniero:

Ao tentar executar conforme a resposta, foi gerado o erro:

[image: IDE mostrando o erro]

Atualização ref. ao comentado do @LINQ:

Alterei a variável do `Count` para uma variável do tipo `int`:

[image: outro erro]

Comment: Como é que você pretende aplicar um `Count` passando uma `string`? Você quer contar os modelos que não sejam nulos?

Comment: @Linq, me corrija se estiver errado por favor, No sql, eu consigo contar, mesmo que for do tipo `Varchar` certo? porque aqui não? alterei, para um variavel INT e ainda assim continua o erro.

Comment: Não, você está confundindo as coisas. Você precisa saber **o que** quer contar. O `Count` recebe um predicado e não um elemento. E no SQL não existe "contar mesmo que seja varchar", se você pôr uma coluna no count vai ser validado se aquela coluna é nula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *query* está certa mesmo? É isso que quer? Então em LINQ vai usar [`Max()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.max?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Queryable_Max__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__), [`Count()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.count?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Queryable_Count__1_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__) e [`GroupBy()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupby?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupBy__2_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___). Não garanto o jeito exato, mas é algo assim:

```
var query = from s in db.Crm_Analise
                group s by s.TAG into g
                where s.cliente_CRM == cod_cli
                select new {TAG = g.TAG, ATUALIZAÇÂO = g.Max(t => t.data_creat), RELATÓRIOS = g.Count(t => t.modelo != null)};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/MaxCount.cs).

Comment: bom dia, obrigado pela ajuda, mas esta me retornando um erro.. fiz uma atualização na pergunta com a imagem do erro, tambem fiquei com uma duvida, a clausura `Where` tem que vir antes do  `Group By` certo?

Comment: Responda ao que o LINQ disse para saber o que fazer. Eu achei que teria esse e até outros problemas. Se for o que ele comentou eu mudo na resposta, é só verificar se não é nulo, embora eu acho essa contagem bem esquisita.

Comment: Eu queria contar, quantas vezes a TAG se repete dentro da lista, por isso o Count.. obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

O `Count` no SQL, quando recebe um campo, retorna a contagem de **todas as linhas** da tabela **menos** aquelas onde o campo passado for nulo.

No LINQ, o `Count` sempre recebe um predicado e não um elemento, então, para simular o efeito do SQL, você precisa fazer uma condição com o campo.

```
var query = from s in db.Crm_Analise
            where s.cliente_CRM == cod_cli
            group s by s.TAG into g
            select new 
            {
                TAG = g.TAG, 
                ATUALIZAÇÂO = g.Max(t => t.data_creat), 
                RELATÓRIOS = g.Count(t => t.modelo != null)
            };
```

Comment: No LINQ ... referencia circular  ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) ...